# Ayuda con SQL SERVER BASICO

Tags: sql, sql-server

Agradecería su ayuda en SQL.
Lo intente hacer con WHEN MONTH(FInicio) = 1 THEN EXC_ENERO...Sucesivamente con todos los meses pero no me funciona

Tengo una tabla similar a la que muestro, cada columna representa un mes, estoy tratando de hacer un query que me obtenga la suma de los meses según un rango de fecha, pero solo obtengo resultado de un mes usando case when

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en el rango de fecha pongo WHERE ."Fecha" BETWEEN (1ero de enero) AND (31 de marzo) me muestre la suma de los 3 meses en una columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de Antemano

Comment: Si la respuesta que te han dado, no es lo que esperas, puede ser posible que tú escenario no se comprenda del todo. Si pones la estructura de la tabla que tienes, y el resultado final. No solo la columna de la suma, sino el resto, para saber como plantearte la respuesta

Comment: Si, tiene razon, platee con poca información mi pregunta, ya lo añadí de forma correcta abajo, si fuera posible agradeceria su ayuda sobre que podria hacer, gracias @Javi fer2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tu quieres realizar es un *pivote* de información, lo cual se realiza con la clausula [`pivot`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).

Suponiendo que tienes una tabla de base con los campos:

```
  ID      int, varchar, nvarchar, etc.
  Fecha   date, datetime
  Valor   int, numeric, money, etc.
```

Puedes tomar los datos de la tabla, obtener la sumatoria de la columna `valor` para cada mes y colocar la información en columnas, una para cada mes, en una sola sentencia SQL.

La idea básica es hacer una consulta que nos devuelva el valor numérico del mes, por ejemplo valiéndonos de la función `month()`:

La siguiente consulta, por ejemplo, nos devuelve los registros del año 2020 con el ID, el número del mes y el valor:

```
select   a.ID
       , month(a.Fecha) mes
       , a.valor 
  from MiTabla a
 where year(a.fecha) = 2020
```

Metemos esa consulta en el `pivot`, de esta manera:

```
select   ID
       , [1] as Enero
       , [2] as Febrero
       , [3] as Marzo
  from (select   a.ID
               , month(a.Fecha) mes
               , a.valor 
          from MiTabla a
         where year(a.fecha) = 2020
       ) as TablaBase
 pivot (    sum(valor)
        for mes in ([1], [2], [3])
       ) as Pivote
```

Si te fijas, en la primera parte, vamos tomando los posibles valores de la columna `mes`, como si se tratase de nuevas columnas (dado que son numéricos, es obligatorio el uso de `[]`) y en la misma, le voy dando un alias a cada uno: 1 es Enero, 2 Febrero, etc.

En el `from` le damos la consulta que habíamos preparado inicialmente y luego en la clausula `pivot` indicamos la operación de agregación a realizar `sum(valor)` y todos los posibles valores de la columna mes para los que queremos realizar esta acción.

El resultado es este:

```
ID      Enero   Febrero Marzo
A       5       10      55
B       4       1       5
C       3       7       4
D       1       1       1
E       3       6       3
F       1       2       7
G       5       3       2

(7 rows affected)

Completion time: 2020-09-01T23:57:12.4364368-06:00
```

He preparado el ejemplo con solo 3 meses, ya tu puedes adaptarlo al año completo, o los meses que necesites.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, deje un comentario abajo de lo que busco exactamente, no se si me puedas orientar, muchas gracias enserio, eres mi salvación ya que no veo forma como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

@jachguate MUCHAS GRACIAS por su respuesta
Tal vez no me explique muy bien lo siguiente es my query, esta hecho en hana de sap pero básicamente cumple lo mismo que sql,
Necesito añadir un campo llamado (presupuesto) de otra tabla (que es la sumatoria de los meses que rangee)

```
SELECT T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2" as "Cuenta", 
T1."AcctName",
T1."AccntntCod",
sum(T0."Debit"-T0."Credit") as "Saldo_SOL",
sum(T0."SYSDeb"-T0."SYSCred") as "Saldo_ME"

FROM JDT1 T0  
INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode"
INNER JOIN "@EXC_RUBROS" T2 ON T1."U_EXC_OPEREXPEN" = T2."U_EXC_CODRUB"

WHERE T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20200331'

group by T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2", T1."AcctName",T1."AccntntCod"
order by T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2"
```

Este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debo añadir es la siguiente tabla donde las columnas representan meses, y tengo que acumularlos en un campo llamado presupuesto segun el rango de fecha, esta tabla se relaciona con el query anterior, con las columnas  (U_EXC_CTACON = Cuenta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es una parte de reporte final y la data acumulada de los meses tiene que ir Acumulado en  Prespto M.E

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias de antemano por su ayuda  @jachguate, @Javi fer2

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] (de nuevo) para aprender como funciona el sitio.  Si tu problema no fue bien planteado al inicio, tienes la opción de editar la pregunta, esta vez añadiendo la información necesaria para que se entienda con mayor claridad cual es tu problema, incluyendo las etiquetas relevantes. Dado que eso podría invalidar las respuestas recibidas, si consideras que hay buenas respuestas, otra opción es dejar esto como está, quizás aceptar una respuesta y realizar una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y borra esta no-respuesta.